# what is the argument of 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

When $z\neq 0$, $\arg z$ is defined to be the set $\{\theta \in \mathbb{R} : z=|z|e^{i\theta}\}$.

What if $z=0$? Usually does one leave the argument of $0$ undefined? Or is $\arg 0 = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: Yes, either undefined, or any real number is an argument of $0$. Whichever choice is more convenient.

Comment: @DanielFischer Which one is your definition? I think it's uncomfortable to do arithmetic on sets such as $\arg z + \arg w = \arg (z+w)$ if $\arg 0$ is left undefined. Moreover, if $\arg 0$ is defined as the real field, then what would be "Arg 0" (principal value) generally?

Comment: Are you sure $\arg z + \arg w = \arg(z+w)$ is correct? What if you take $z=w=i$?

Comment: @5xum i meant $\arg(zw)$. I'm sorry for the typo.

Comment: Most of the time the question doesn't arise, then I leave it undecided. If the question arises, I take the more convenient answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you :)

Comment: @DanielFischer I wish your comments were an answer. It would be an answer to other questions along this line as well.

Answer (score 7):

As has been discussed in the comments, the argument of $0$ is taken to be either zero or undefined. It is a matter of convention.