# Is zero part of this complex set?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to draw the complex set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0\leq \arg(z)\leq \pi/4\}.$ This set contains the area in the $1^{st}$ quadrant between the radial lines drawn at the two angels $0$ and $\pi/4,$ with those lines included. However, the argument of the complex $0$ is not defined in this problem. If I assume [the argument of $0$ is a value between $0$ and $\pi/4,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739462/what-is-the-argument-of-0) then zero is in the set. Since it is not given, what is the solution? Thanks.

Comment: If you have no additional information, omit the point zero.

Comment: It may depend on what you want. You can either attach the number to your set by using union, just as we construct eigenspaces for some eigenvalue taking all eigenvectors and then union $\;\{0\}\;$, or else you can keep it out of the set.

Answer (score 3):

Your set is not well-defined; the notation means nothing. When you write down a set in the form $\{ x \in X : P(x) \}$, then you're implicitly assuming that the assertion "$P(x)$" makes sense for any element $x$ of the set $X$. But here, the assertion "$0 \le \operatorname{arg}(z) \le \pi/4$" is neither true or false for $z = 0$, it's not even defined.

A sensible interpretation for what you've written would then be $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^* : 0 \le \operatorname{arg}(z) \le \pi / 4 \}$, i.e. simply exclude zero. But really you simply shouldn't even write something like this and make sure that whenever you write down something, it's well defined.