# Is it possible to say that $\arg(0)= \infty $ since it's not undefined or it is $0$ since $0|0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, definition, convention

let $z$ be a complex variable and $z=0+0i$ , it is clear at all if want to compute $\arg(z)$ then should be check the value of $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$  then $\tan^{-1}(0/0)$ could be $0$ since $0 |0 $ using the divisibility notion or Is it possible to say that $\arg(0)= \infty $ since it's not undefined  ? Where is the approach definition ?

Comment: It is undefined. It is not $\infty$.

Comment: any proof for that and thanks ? , I seek for the approach definition

Comment: See (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739462/what-is-the-argument-of-0)

Comment: A proof of what? It is a definition (or a non-definition, rather). What would you gain by setting it equal to $\infty$? And what is the "approach definition"?

Comment: I meant approach  to the correct

Comment: Thanks for that explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid talking about branches and multivalued functions as much as possible, then you fix some half-open interval $I$ of length $2\pi$. Given $I$, the definition of $\mathrm{arg}(z)$ is a real number $\theta$ in $I$ such that $z=re^{i\theta}$ for some $r \geq 0$. Such a $\theta$ exists and is unique if $z \neq 0$.

But when $z=0$, $r$ is necessarily zero. At this point, $\theta$ can be any number in $I$, thus $\mathrm{arg}(z)$ is not uniquely defined by the properties that we want it to satisfy.